# how to push programmatically made view controller with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a `TableViewController` and embedded it in a `navigationController` (no storyboards):

```
class editFullnameNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {

        let editFullnameTableViewControllerClass = editFullnameTableViewController(style: .grouped)

        super.init(rootViewController: editFullnameTableViewControllerClass)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

}

class editFullnameTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

}
```

I want to push this `editFullnameTableViewController` with touching a button in another `viewController` using :

```
let editfullnameNavigationControllerPage = editFullnameNavigationController(rootViewController: editFullnameTableViewController(style: .grouped))
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editfullnameNavigationControllerPage, animated: true)
```

but its not working. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Subclassing `UINavigationController` is wrong most of the times.

Comment: can you share code, how you initialised viewController.

Answer (score 0):

just create a instance view controller and push to viewcontroller

```
let controller = editFullnameTableViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

NavigationController Subclass cannot be pushed on NavigationController Stack

You can present it with present method

```
//create instence
let navController = editFullnameTableViewController() //Navigation controller
//present method
self.navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or You can set New Navigation Controller as Root of window

```
self.window?.rootViewController = navController
```

Comment: possibly you can also use self.show() method as well